# Why can't I add a string to my NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have created a function within my code that converts whatever is in the textfield of my app to append to my array. However, when I set a breakpoint in the code, it returns that my array, `_descriptionArray` is nil. Why is that?

I want whatever value is in the `descriptionTextField.text` to append to my `_descriptionArray`.

Thanks for the help!

```
-(NSMutableArray *)descriptionConversion{

    [_descriptionArray addObject: (descriptionTextField.text)];


    return _descriptionArray;
}
```

Comment: alloc/init doesn't seems to be done...

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever initialize `_descriptionArray`? If not, be sure to initialize the array with `_descriptionArray = [NSMutableArray array];`. If you don't initialize the array, it will be nil. You can only add an object to an array; not to nil.